# Understanding what find_elements_by_xpath returns in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

This is my code:

```py
mydata = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/section/div/div/div[1]/div[4]/div/table/tbody[1]/tr/td[3]')
print(mydata)
```

It returns:

```
[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="70471ea3d46485ab51b62586ffa7ff21", element="4877016a-a335-47f7-b46d-52dbc3604dce")>].
```

How do I understand this result?

Comment: All functions with pattern `find_elements_*()`  returns list of matching web elements of the parameter(id, class, tag, xpath). And you are getting the unique id of every matching element of xpath.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/section/div/div/div[1]/div[4]/div/table/tbody[1]/tr/td[3]')
for element in elements:
    print(element) # prints element
    print(element.id) # prints the id of element
    print(element.text) # prints the text of element
    print(element.size) # prints the size of element
    print(element.location) # prints the location of element
    print(element.parent) # prints the text of element
```

When you use `driver.find_elements_by_xpath()`, as the name implies, you get multiple elements (stored in a list). To investigate all elements, you need to loop through all of them using `for element in elements`.

To find out what kind of information you can get (by accessing its attributes or calling its methods), you can [check the docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html?highlight=text#module-selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement), e.g., `id`, `location`, `tag_name`, `size`, `text`.

Answer (score -1):

```py
mydata = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/section/div/div/div[1]/div[4]/div/table/tbody[1]/tr/td[3]')
# this will print the text written within tags
print(mydata.text)
```

`mydata` is an object and you can perform opeation on this, like get text or get parent, send keys etc.

Comment: I've already tried it. It returns AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'. Error...